# How to get all branches from git remote repository for a specific user

Tags: git, get, grep, gitlab, pull

I need to get all my branches (the one I had created) from the git remote server(origin) and then remove them.

Comment: What do you mean by "your" branches? A git branch is assigned to a specific commit, not to a user.

Comment: which I had created and then left over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way how to represent all branches I ever created on the remote server.
List all remote branches with the specific username:

> git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n | grep Username